# How to show zsh function definition (like bash "type myfunc")?

Tags: bash, function, zsh, definition

How do I show the definition of a function in zsh? `type foo` doesn't give the definition.

In bash:

```
bash$ function foo() { echo hello; }

bash$ foo
hello

bash$ type foo
foo is a function
foo () 
{ 
    echo hello
}
```

In zsh:

```
zsh$ function foo() { echo hello; }

zsh$ foo
hello

zsh$ type foo
foo is a shell function
```

Comment: `declare -f foo` is the better choice even in bash - and it works in `zsh` too; see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26911615/45375) for background.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

The zsh idiom is `whence`, the `-f` flag prints function definitions:

```
zsh$ whence -f foo
foo () {
    echo hello
}
zsh$
```

In zsh, `type` is defined as equivalent to `whence -v`, so you can continue to use `type`, but you'll need to use the `-f` argument:

```
zsh$ type -f foo
foo () {
    echo hello
}
zsh$
```

And, finally, in zsh `which` is defined as equivalent to `whence -c` - print results in *csh-like* format, so `which foo` will yield the same results.

`man zshbuiltins` for all of this.

Comment: "whence" just returns the name of the function.  It does not show the function definition.

Comment: @RobBednark look more closely: `-f` is used in the answer, which does print function definitions

Comment: `type -f foo` also does this; `type` is equivalent to `whence -v`.

Comment: I see, "whence -f foo" does give the behavior that I'm looking for.  Equivalent to Thor's "which foo".

Comment: @pb2q, nice details for the 3 different ways, as well as the reference.  Thanks!

Comment: Works, but only if no alias of the same name happens to be defined, in which case that is reported (`whence -f`, `type -f`, `which` report the highest-precedence form of the command).

Comment: Warning to other RHEL6/Centos6 users:  I'm picking up an alias for `which` from `/etc/profile.d/which2.sh`, which comes from the `which` package.

Comment: declare -f foo (see below) is better because even if the function is hidden by an alias, it will still be shown, whereas 'whence' is liable to show just the alias, OR both the alias and the function.

Comment: Bonus: if you use `type`/`whence -v` you will get the filename where the function is defined: for example the command `type rvm_prompt_info` gives `rvm_prompt_info is a shell function from /home/cristian/.oh-my-zsh/lib/prompt_info_functions.zsh`

Answer (score 32):

I've always just used `which` for this.

Comment: "which" gives the behavior I'm looking for -- thanks Thor!  (Note that "which" is a zsh builtin whereas in bash it calls /usr/bin/which , and /usr/bin/which has different behavior than the zsh builtin function "which")

Comment: Works, but only if no alias of the same name happens to be defined, in which case _that_ is reported (`which` reports the highest-precedence form of the command).

Answer (score 25):

```
declare -f foo  # works in zsh and bash

typeset -f foo  # works in zsh, bash, and ksh
```

If you don't mind or prefer including *all* command forms that exist for a given name in the output:<sup>Thanks, [Raine Revere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/480608/raine-revere).</sup>

```
type -af  # zsh only (works differently in bash and ksh)
```

---

`type -f` / `whence -f` / `which` are suboptimal in this case, because their purpose is to report the command form with the *highest precedence* that *happens to be defined* by that name - as opposed to specifically reporting on the operand as a *function*.

That said, in practice this means that only an *alias* of the same name takes precedence (and technically also a *shell keyword*, though naming functions for shell keywords is probably a bad idea anyway).

Note that `zsh` does expand aliases in scripts by default (as does `ksh`, but not `bash`), and even if you turn alias expansion off first, `type -f` / `whence -f` / `which` *still* report aliases first.

In `zsh`, the `-f` option only *includes* shell functions in the lookup in `zsh`, so - unless `-a` is also used to list *all* command forms - an alias by the given name would print as the only output.

In `bash` and `ksh`, `type -f` actually *excludes* functions from the lookup; `whence` doesn't exist in `bash`, and in `ksh` it doesn't print the function *definition*; `which` is not a builtin in `ksh` and `bash`, and the external utility by definition cannot print shell functions.

Answer (score 9):

If you're not quite sure what you are looking for, you can type just

```
functions
```

and it will show you all the defined functions.

Note that there are sometimes a LOT of them, so you might want to pipe to a pager program:

```
functions | less
```

to undefine a function, use

```
unfunction functionname
```

Comment: +1; Note that `functions` is equivalent to `typeset -f` (except for the `-M` option), so you can even use the grammatically slightly counter-intuitive command `functions foo` to get information about a _given_ function.